# cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called for non visible cells also

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4.2

tableview data source method    cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called for the non visible rows also which is creating a problem in pagination in tableview. Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Just because it is not visible on your screen doesn't mean it is not visible. What is visible and not visible is decided by your tableView frame. Check your table view frame. Also, elaborate your question with screenshots and code.

Comment: Use prefetch data source property for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The system calls this method to prepare cells ahead of time, so scrolling is smoother and more responsive. If you want to fetch more data as the user scrolls down/up you should rather implement `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` - this method is called just before the cell is displayed to the user.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) is also getting called for non visible cells

Comment: Have you set your delegates in viewDidLoad?